# Why does Scala do this when I'm trying to convert from Radians/Degrees and vice-versa?

Tags: scala, math

Let's assume I have a method that takes in a Int and returns the sin of the input.

```
def sinTest(x: Int): Double = {
    Math.sin(x)
}
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(sinTest(30))
  }
```

The output for this code is: `-0.9880316240928618` (as expected).
However, when I change Math.sin(x) to Math.sin(x.toDegrees), it gives me this: `-0.40979706006803573`

Shouldn't it be giving me 0.5? Why is it returning this number?
However, when I do Math.sin(x.toRadians), it gives me this: `0.5000000126183913`

Why is that when I switch it to radians, it gives me 0.5 when in reality it should be giving 0.5 when I convert to degrees?

Comment: No. `Math.sin` takes a double in radians, and you need to convert the 30 degrees you have `toRadians` for that.

Comment: Notice that `toDegrees` does not mean to interpret a "dimensionless 30" *as* degrees, but rather to *convert* radians *to* degrees.

Comment: Then what is -0.9880316240928618. When I convert back shouldn't it be giving the same result?

Comment: -0.9880316240928618 is the sin of 30 radians. What do you mean by "when I convert back?"

Comment: That's what's confusing me. I get 3 different numbers. Math.sin(x) returns -0.9880316240928618. Math.sin(x.toDegrees) gives -0.40979706006803573. Math.sin(x.toRadians) gives 0.5000000126183913.

Comment: Math.sin(x.toDegrees) doesn't make sense to do because Math.sin doesn't take degrees.